# Necesito que el formulario agrege los datos a la tabla, al igual necesito que la modal se abra cuando le click en el botos Detalles

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db('kenworth',$con);

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$entrega = $_POST['entrega'];
$devolucion = $_POST['devolucion'];
$concepto = $_POST['concepto'];
$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

 $req = (strlen($nombre)*strlen($entrega)*strlen($devolucion)*strlen($concepto)*strlen($cantidad)*strlen($descripcion)) or die("No se han llenado los campos");

 mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Prestamos VALUES ('$nombre','$entrega','$devolucion','$concepto','$cantidad','$descripcion')");

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">    

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Solicitud de prestamos</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1maximum-scale=1user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/materialize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/fakeLoader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spinnaker" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/fakeLoader.css">
    </head>


    <body style="background:#424242;">
        <div class="input-field col s12 center">
         <img src="static/img/logo.png" alt="" class="responsive-img" width="700px">
         <h2 class="black-text">Prestamos de equipo de cómputo</h2>
        </div>
          <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s5">
    <label for="first_name" >Nombre/Destino</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="validate">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4">
        <input type="text" name="entrega" class="datepicker">
        <label for="first_name">Entrega de prestamo</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
        <input type="text" name="devolucion" class="datepicker">
        <label for="first_name">Devolución del prestamo</label>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <label>Seleciona un concepto</label>
  <select name="concepto" class="input-field col s12">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Elije tu opción</option>
    <option value="1">Equipo de computo</option>
    <option value="2">Material diverso u otro</option>
  </select>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col s6">
    <label for="first_name" >Cantidad</label>
     <input name="cantidad" type="number"> 
     </div>
     <div class="input-field col s6">
     <label for="Des">Descripción del equipo</label>
     <input name="descripcion" type="text"> 
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
  <input type="submit" value="Guardar"  style="background-color:#607d8b;">
  <input type="reset" style="background-color:#607d8b;" id="guardar" value="Limpiar">      
  </div>

<table id="tabla_prestamo" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Nombre</td>   
    <td>Entrega del prestamo</td>
    <td>Devoluación del prestamo</td>
    <td>Concepto</td>
    <td>Cantidad</td>
    <td>Descripción del equipo</td>
    <td>Detalles</td>
  </tr>

<?php

 $sql="SELECT * FROM prestamos";
 $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);

while ($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  # code...

?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['Destino']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['Fecha_Entrega']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_Devolucion']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['Concepto']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['Cantidad']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['Descripción']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['Detalles']?><a href="#pruebamodal" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger">Detalles</a></td>

  </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="pruebamodal" class="modal">
      <h4>Ejemplo de modal</h4>
      <p>A ver si funciona por que no me abre la modal</p>
      <p> no se por que</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <?php
   }
    ?>

<style>
 table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow: auto;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #757575;
}
</style>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/materialize-01.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="reg.php" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('select').material_select();
         });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('.datepicker').pickadate({
                selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
                selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
                today: 'Today',
                clear: 'Clear',
                close: 'Ok',
                closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
            });
    </script>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#guardar').click(function(){
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        var entrega = document.getElementById("entrega").value;
        var devolucion = document.getElementById("devolucion").value;
        var concepto = document.getElementById("concepto").value;
        var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
        var descripcion = document.getElementById("descripcion").value;
        var i = 1;
        var fila = '<tr id="row'+ i + '"><td>' + nombre + '</td><td>' + entrega + '</td><td>' + devolucion + '</td><td>' + concepto + '</td><td>' + cantidad + '</td><td>' + descripcion + '</td><td><button type="button" name="detalle" id"' + i + '" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn_detalle" style="width:80px">Detalle</button></td></tr>'; 
        i++;

        $('#tabla_prestamo tr:first').after(fila);
        var nfilas = $("#tabla_prestamo tr").length;

        document.getElementById("descripcion").value = "";
        document.getElementById("cantidad").value = "";
        document.getElementById("concepto").value = "";
        document.getElementById("devolucion").value = "";
        document.getElementById("entrega").value = "";
        document.getElementById("nombre").value = "";
        document.getElementById("nombre").focus();        
      });
      $(document).on ('click', 'btn_detalle', function(){
        var buton_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#row' + buton_id + '').

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
  });
         $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
  });
      });



    });


    </script>

          </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, mucho gusto, es un placer tenerte como parte de esta comunidad, te invito a que leas el centro de ayuda de como preguntar, [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), por otro lado revisa una de mis preguntas sobre modales, la cual te puede servir [Como mostrar modal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/222237/problema-al-mostrar-datos-en-modal-desde-bd-en-laravel)

Comment: lo de la modal de bootstrap te sugiero que revises como debes definir o cargar tus librerias de Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template

Comment: probe tu codigo y la modal ni siquiera se construye se da errores, por lo cual debes ver el orden en que debes cargar