# Mostrar datos a través de un modal

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de que me muestre una imagen que tengo en mi base de datos a través de un modal, me muestra la imagen pero se me repite la primera imagen en todos los modales, es decir, tengo 10 registros y se me repite la primera imagen en todos los registros.

Esté es todo mi código:

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');    
    include './config/config.php';    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM img";
    $ans = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ans)){        
        $id = $row['id'];
        $soli = $row['solicitud'];
        $img = $row['img'];         
        //var_dump($img);        
        $image = base64_decode($img);  
        $final_image = base64_encode($image);
?>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data- 
  toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Ver solicitud
  </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Solicitud número <?php echo $soli ?></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img id="myImg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo  $final_image ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ¿Revisaste el contenido de tu tabla? El código parece correcto, si se repiten datos, puede que esos datos estén repetidos en la tabla que estás consultando... Supongo que el contenido HTML al final del código debe aparecer por cada fila de la tabla ¿no?

Comment: @A.Cedano En la tabla guarde imágenes distintas, cuando pongo las imágenes en una etiqueta <img> me aparecen y ninguna se repite

Comment: investigue en siguiente problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/223924/45023

Comment: ¿Y entonces dónde es que se repiten las imágenes?

Comment: @A.Cedano con todas los registros que tengo en cada uno tengo una imagen pero en vez de verse la imagen de ese registro se ve la misma imagen para todos

Comment: ¿Te refieres a esto exactamente: `<img id="myImg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo  $final_image ?>">`? ¿Si activas el `var_dump` que hay en el `while` muestra en cada caso una imagen distinta?

Comment: cuando quito el modal y cargo la imagen en esa etiqueta, me muestra todas las imágenes correctamente, sin repetirse ninguna

Comment: Estás creando una modal para cada registro, pero todas tienen mismo ID, por eso es que siempre se muestra la misma. Podrías asignar ID dinámico a cada modal o, mejor aún, crear una sola ventana modal y agregar la información necesaria dentro del botón con [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) y usarlos para actualizar la ventana cuando se abra.

Comment: @Triby o no usar en absoluto el modal. Realmente, aunque veo que a algunos les encantan los modales, ese era el boom de los años 90, a causa de Windows, pero hoy día, con todas las posibilidades que da Javascript, no tiene prácticamente ningún sentido usar modales. Por lo general empobrecen la UX teniendo que moverte entre la pantalla principal y el modal, etc. Para lo único que usaría un modal sería para un cuadro de diálogo cuya acción sea obligatoria antes de pasar a otra cosa, pero para mostrar información tipo detalle o cosas así, es mejor integrarlo en el mismo contenedor.

Comment: consejo, usa un solo modal y carga las imagenes con JS, asi no sobrecargas con código repetido y es fácil saber que es lo que estas mostrando en el modal

Comment: @A.Cedano, es cuestión de preferencias y puntos de vista. El boom de los 90 fue basado en popups y era realmente una mala experiencia. En parte, tienes razón, pero dependiendo de cada caso de uso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prueba algo como este ejemplo, que genera un modal aleatorio cada ves que se invoca

```js
function addmodalb4(id){ // carga un modal para usarlo con referencia en id
    let elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.innerHTML=`
                <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_b4_`+id+`" data-backdrop="static"  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="Modal_b4_titulo`+id+`">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                        </div> 
            <div class="modal-body"   id="Modal_b4_`+id+`_conten">
                        
                        </div>
                        <div id="Modal_b4_`+id+`_modal_footer" class="modal-footer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
function creaModal(titulo,mensaje){
let Nid=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + 1;
    addmodalb4(Nid); //Genera nuevo modal random ID
    $('#Modal_b4_'+Nid).modal();
    $('#Modal_b4_titulo'+Nid).html(titulo);
    $('#Modal_b4_'+Nid+'_conten').html('<img src="'+mensaje+'">');
 }
```

```css
.b{  padding: 10px;  background-color: aliceblue;  width: 100px; margin: 5px;  float: left;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="b" onClick="creaModal('Este es un modal 1','https://i.picsum.photos/id/535/300/300.jpg?hmac=crYGpbcKPzOGYWJYYUgrnI9hQeZN-KiypxKYh1-EW1E');">imagen 1</div>
<div class="b" onClick="creaModal('Este es un modal 2','https://i.picsum.photos/id/856/300/300.jpg?hmac=K6AeHs9gpB-QHPd5KecDYgrBll0Lq6Lh6nb_nsH2Cic');">imagen 2</div>
<div class="b" onClick="creaModal('Este es un modal 3','https://i.picsum.photos/id/480/300/300.jpg?hmac=SNeDbPA-87bxLtQ9W6l9Dy1QvsNoJhqR6IBDH5ACSHk');">imagen 3</div>
<div class="b" onClick="creaModal('Este es un modal 4','https://i.picsum.photos/id/781/300/300.jpg?hmac=TKvIU2oKRGUW2wfK_7ckbYvHIwgcA92KdsTQJD7YHco');">imagen 4</div>
```